# google web toolkit- Sending a String from Java to JavaScript Code

Tags: gwt

I'm working on my first web app, and I'm using gwt to build it.

This app implements external hand-written JavaScript Code (which I'm not familiar with). 
Well, I need to set a String variable within Java and pass  it to a JavaScript Object.

the interesting part of my html looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  var b = new Browser({
                                             containerID: "TheApp",
                                             Data: Info,
                                             bookmark: bookmarkCallback,
                                             dataPath:"pathToData/"
                                                     }); </script>
```

And now, I would like to set the dataPath in Java and pass it over to "pathTOData"

How exactly could i do it?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing string info you can use [Dictionary class](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html) it is allowing you to access to external JS objects defined on host page.

But your case and object is more complex, so most likely  you will have to use [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)  and [JavaScript Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html)

Comment: Thx, i need a JSNI method form java to js.